# Performance of changing the position of hundreds of WinForms controls

Tags: .net, winforms, performance

I have a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < panel1->Controls->Count; ++i) {
    Control^ ctl = panel1->Controls[i];
    ctl->Location.Y = i*10;
}
```

Is it okay if I have 200 or 300 controls in panel1?
Or it will be better if I add this:

```
if (ctl->Location.Y != i*10) ctl->Location.Y = i*10;
```

I just don't know if .NET's controls will repaint anyway (it will take time) or they will automatically check if there is no need to repaint (still same location)

Comment: I think you can suspend rendering/relayouting, which might speed up this code.

Comment: In situations like these, your best friend is a decompiler like Reflector.

Comment: @leppie I'd rather benchmark it first.

Comment: I would use a profiler to determine the best course of action.

Comment: this is one of those times I'd say: You already have two options. Why don't you just try it both ways? Find out what works better in your case?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: And you would still be none the wiser ;p

Comment: Having hundreds of controls in a panel is never okay, it makes for a very sluggish UI.  The code resembles a painful way to substitute the Panel.AutoScroll property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can optimize it like follows to avoid continuous repainting:

```
panel1.SuspendLayout();

for (int i = 0; i < panel1->Controls->Count; ++i) {
{
    // do reposition
}   

panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
panel1.PerformLayout();
```

or

```
panel1.ResumeLayout()
```

@CodesInChaos: Good point!
It looks to be the same, but it isn't. To use

- ResumeLayout(false)/PerformLayout() or
- ResumeLayout()

will influence how the result looks like as explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/12/16/504957.aspx).

Comment: Why `ResumeLayout(false)`+`PerformLayout()` instead of `ResumeLayout()`?